# Using a clock while loop to read files in a while loop

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, java.util.scanner, clock

Currently taking my Data Structures class and we're to employ a queue in our next program.

We are given an input file such as this one:

```
10 324 Boots 32.33
11 365 Gloves 33.33
12 384 Sweater 36.33
13 414 Blouse 35.33
```

I am to read the first int (which is a unit of time) and use that as a reference for my clock that keeps running in the background.

I did something along these lines:

```
Scanner infp = new Scanner(new File(FILE));
while (busy) {
    clock = 0;
    clock += clockCount++;

    while (infp.hasNext()) {
        timeEntered = infp.nextInt();
        infp.nextLine();

        System.out.println(timeEntered);
        busy = true;

        if (timeEntered == clock) {
            itemNum = infp.nextInt();
            type = infp.nextLine();
            itemPrice = infp.nextDouble();  
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I run it I get an 'InputMismatchException' error. I'm cognizant of the fact that you need to skip the carriage before a String, which is what I believe I am doing.

I have no clue where to go from here.

Comment: Your mistake is at type = infp.nextLine(). It reads an entire line. You should read your line with read line and use the String split method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So given these columns:

```
10 324 Boots 32.33
11 365 Gloves 33.33
12 384 Sweater 36.33
13 414 Blouse 35.33
```

For each line, you read the first column into `timeEntered`.
And then you do `infp.nextLine()` and that's a mistake.
When you call `nextLine`, the scanner reads everything unread on the current line until the end.
That means you cannot read the other column values.
But you need them. So don't call `nextLine` when you still want to process values on a line. Call it after.

And you have the exact same kind of problem again later when your read `type` and `itemPrice`.

Replace the `while (infp.hasNext())` with this:

```
while (infp.hasNextLine()) {
    int timeEntered = infp.nextInt();

    System.out.println(timeEntered);
    busy = true;

    if (timeEntered == clock) {
        itemNum = infp.nextInt();
        type = infp.next();
        itemPrice = infp.nextDouble();
    }
    infp.nextLine();
}
```